# "den Hals umdrehen"

Tags: german-to-english, idiom

This idiom is used in a fable from "Bechsteins Märchen" in a few places.  Here is one example:

> "Auf der Stelle sollst du sterben dafür, dass du mir hast wollen den Hals umdrehen".

I want to know what it means in English.  The literal translation does not make sense to me.

I thought it might mean `"to chop off the head"`.  There is an English expression `"to wring someone's neck"` which means "to do violence to someone" so perhaps that is what is meant, but I am just guessing.

Answer (score 6):

Your assumption is correct - it actually means "to break someone's neck", or (more figuratively), generally "to kill someone".

It is assumed to stem from the barbaric way chicken used to be slaughtered.

Comment: The easiest way to kill a bird is to grab its body and head and wring the neck. That's where the idiom originates.

Comment: I do not think that this is any more barbaric than how chicken are treated today. Of course, you did not say that it is.